# How to print to view 1 object multilevel

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I use AngularJS. How to print to view 1 object multilevel when I haven't defined the inside attributes.

For example, I have object error:

```
{
  "email": {
    "Required": []
  },
   "first_name": {
    "Min": [
      "2"
    ]
  },
  "last_name": {
    "Required": []
  }
}
```

I want to print all the data in this object formed list

- email: Required
- first_name:Min 2
- last_name: Required
- ...

Please imagine that this is just one part in many errors that may happens when submitting form.

Comment: Hi Would you please elaborate on what exactly you need.

Comment: I want to print all the data in this object formed list <ul><li>..</li></ul>. Please imagine that this is just one part in many errors that may happens when submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

The DOT notation of reading objects or properties nested deep within an existing object works with AngularJS too.

Let us say you have the following object:

```
$scope.newObject = {
    email: {
        required: true
    },
    firstName: {
        min: 2
    }.
    lastName: {
        required: true
    }
};
```

If you wish to then access the `required` property of the nested `email` object, then you can access it like so:

```
<input type="text" ng-required="newObject.email.required">
```

Thus using the DOT notation, we can access the nested objects and their properties too.

Comment: I want to print all the data in this object formed list <ul><li>..</li></ul>. Please imagine that this is just one part in many errors that may happens when submitting form.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="obj in newObject">
      <span >{{obj.email.required}}</span>
      <span >{{obj.email.firstname.min}}</span>
      <span >{{obj.email.lastname.required}}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

I hope this may help you